# Create markup for 'hover' effect

Tags: html, css

I have container for video which looks like this:
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Gtc.png)

HTML:

```
  <div class="video-item col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="opacity-layer"></div>
      <div class="play-block">
          <div class="landing-play-button"></div>
      </div>
      <img src="image.jpg">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.opacity-layer{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.play-block{
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 55%;
    border: solid white 4px;
    margin: 5% 5%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    /*background-color: #f5f5f5;*/
    cursor: pointer;
}

.play-block:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

and on "hover" I want remove 'opacity-layer' only within 'play-block', something like here: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F699A.png).

Comment: Assuming that the  'opacity-layer'  covers the whole 'video-item' div...it's not possible to remove it from *part* of that div.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need advice how to correct my markup for effect like on second screenshot. @Paulie_D

Comment: You'd need two overlays...one covering the top section, another covering the bottom. If you have a demo it would be simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using multiple `borders` or `outline`, then fade out the b`ackground-color` on `hover`. I used `outline` for this example - https://jsfiddle.net/ea90qjae/

It's by now means the finished solution, but it should give you a starter for ten

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.play-block:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the opacity-layer to be invisible on `:hover` then I'd suggest the easiest way:

```
.video-item:hover .opacity-layer {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Will that solve the issue?

Edit:
Here's an idea:

```
<div class="video-item col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="play-block">
      <div class="covers-only-play-block">
          <div class="landing-play-button"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.covers-only-play-block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; /* 1 is a placeholder, it needs to be lower than the one for the play button, though */
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .5;
}
.video-item:hover .covers-only-play-block {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need. As you can see on second screenshot - I don't want remove all 'opacity' ,  only within 'play-block'.

Comment: Edited my answer @Pasha Does that work for you then?